# Unable to install curl in Ubuntu 18

Tags: curl

I've Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-65-generic x86_64) and I need to install curl, but I'm getting this error, any help?

```
admin@mail:~$ sudo apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.14) but 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or Ubuntu 18.10?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1227385/edit) your question and update to what version you are using.

Comment: Looks like you have at least one 16.04 (Xenial) source installed. Delete all wrong-version sources. Then run `sudo apt update` because your sources changed. Then try installing curl again.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. How can I delete all wrong-version sources?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Unfortunately no... I don't see any broken packages:`dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` returns nothing. But this: `dpkg --get-selections | grep curl` returned this: 
`libcurl3:amd64                                  install
libcurl3-gnutls:amd64                           install
libcurl4-openssl-dev:amd64                      install
php-curl                                        install
php7.0-curl                                     install
php7.2-curl                                     deinstall
python3-pycurl                                  install
`

Comment: Should I uninstall libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.14) first? And try again? How can I do it?

Comment: If the `libcurl3-gnutls` is installed, remove it first.  However, if you run `apt-cache madison curl` and `apt-cache madison libcurl3-gnutls` you should see the versions match.  If they are not, then something in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file might not be configured properly, or a repository in there is incorrect for 18.04 when they should all be set as `bionic`.  Or some sort of 3rd party repository / PPA is setup on your system overriding it.  The `apt-cache madison` commands do show you where those versions are coming from.

Comment: One other thing you can try if multiple versions of `curl` are available is to specify the version you want to install.  `sudo apt install curl=7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8`